# Symfony Routing with variable host

Tags: symfony, routes

I am using the current version of Symfony and want to define a route with a specific subdomain. This is what I have:

```
xyz:
    resource: "@XYZ/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "xyz.symfony.dev"
```

I want to have `symfony.dev` variable, only `xyz` as a subdomain is a static value. How can I realize this? I don't get it in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not good with regex but this answer your question:

```
xyz:
    resource: "@XYZ/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     "xyz.{domain}.{ltd}"
    requirements:
        domain: "([a-z0-9-])+"
        ltd: "([a-z])+"
```

**EDIT**: Regex added

Comment: This answer is useless without the regex

Comment: As described in the [documentation linked by you in the question](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html), this works because `placeholders` serve to specify in the `requirements` space what you need to match (and where is also allowed the use of regex to match any kind of variable coming from `placeholders`). With a little of googling you can find tons of tutorials and references. There are also many websites [like this](http://www.regexr.com) that allows you to build and test online any kind of Regex.